# Azure VM belonging to multiple cloud services

Tags: windows, networking, iis, azure, cloud

I am brand new to Azure and still trying to figure everything out so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to take one VM running IIS and to host multiple websites on it, each with a different SSL certificate. Therefore, I assume I need multiple cloud services (with multiple public IP's) and also multiple internal IP's on the VM (to bind each SSL cert to a unique IP).

Is that the wrong way of thinking about this scenario in Azure? If not, how do I add a VM to multiple cloud services, and also how do I assign multiple internal IP's to a VM?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132756/azure-vm-more-than-one-public-ip

Also, a single IaaS VM can belong to only one cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run multiple websites using Azure, it's not necessary to use IaaS. You can run up to 10 web roles for free - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/